# Use LibGit2Sharp at Azure Cloud Service

Tags: git, azure, libgit2, libgit2sharp, azure-cloud-services

I created a Cloud Service type solution in Microsoft Azure. This solution has got one worker role project.

I want to clone one repository with the worker role using LibGit2Sharp library.

Just simple:

```
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        string workingDir = @"E:\TestRepos\testrepo3";

        string repoUrl = "https://github.com/xx/xx.git";

        string repoPath = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(repoUrl, workingDir);

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

But I got the following error message at the line of Repository.Clone().

[image: error message]

I use this code at my MVC 5 project, and at that case, it works very well. I added the LibGit2Sharp library to the project with Nuget Package Manager.

What do you think, I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this relates to the fact that LibGit2Sharp doesn't cope well (yet) with the Azure publishing mechanism.

This is a known issue (**[kudu#943](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/943)**).

One ongoing PR (**[#705](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/705)**) tackles this through `.props` and `.targets` files in order to make  the `NativeBinaries` folder structure dealt with during the publishing process.

Two other ones (**[#772](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/772)** and **[#778](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/778)**) rather propose to move the native binaries as a separate NuGet packages.

You may be willing to subscribe to those issues in order to get notified of their future progress.